# How can i replace multiple lines in a text file using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a file and i can get 2 lines in the file.I have a file with the following content.

```
public class Websites
{
    //private const string URL = "https://au.yahoo.com/?p=us";
    private const string URL = "https://www.google.com/";
    //private const string URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
          ....
```

I can get the 2 lines individually like so:

```
$linegoogle = Get-Content "C:\myfile.cs" | Select-String "https://www.google.com/" | Select-Object - 
ExpandProperty Line
$google = $linegoogle.Trim()

$linestackoverflow = Get-Content "C:\myfile.cs" | Select-String "https://stackoverflow.com/" | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
$stackoverflow = $linestackoverflow.Trim()
```

But what i wabn to do is the following:

```
if (condition1)
{
    //replace the 2 lines  with
      
      // private const string URL = "https://www.google.com/";  
     private const string URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
}
else if (condition 2)
{
         //replace the 2 lines with

          private const string URL = "https://www.google.com/"; 
         // private const string URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to edit source files like so? Why not put urls in a [config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/store-custom-information-config-file) instead?

Comment: Yes i want to edit the source file. not configs for this .

Comment: Does this answer your question: *use of the [switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-6)*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58182017/1701026

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly not an elegant solution, but this might do it for you:

```
# set the condition here. 
# can be either 'stackoverflow', 'google' or 'yahoo' as per your example file.
$condition = 'stackoverflow'

# read the file as single multiline string
$content = Get-Content "C:\myfile.cs" -Raw
# do the replacements depending on what is in $condition
$result  = switch ($condition) {
    'stackoverflow' {
        $content -replace '(?m)^(\s+)(private const string URL = "https://www\.google\.com/.*";)', '$1//$2' -replace
                          '(?m)^(\s+)(private const string URL = "https://au\.yahoo\.com/.*";)', '$1//$2' -replace
                          '(?m)^(\s+)//(private const string URL = "https://stackoverflow\.com/.*";)', '$1$2'
    }
    'google' {
        $content -replace '(?m)^(\s+)(private const string URL = "https://stackoverflow\.com/.*";)', '$1//$2' -replace
                          '(?m)^(\s+)(private const string URL = "https://au\.yahoo\.com/.*";)', '$1//$2' -replace
                          '(?m)^(\s+)//(private const string URL = "https://www\.google\.com/.*";)', '$1$2'
    }
    'yahoo' {
        $content -replace '(?m)^(\s+)(private const string URL = "https://stackoverflow\.com/.*";)', '$1//$2' -replace
                          '(?m)^(\s+)(private const string URL = "https://www\.google\.com/*";)', '$1//$2' -replace
                          '(?m)^(\s+)//(private const string URL = "https://au\.yahoo\.com/.*";)', '$1$2'
    }
}

# show the result on screen
$result

# write back to file
$result | Set-Content -Path "C:\myfile.cs"
```

Remember that `-replace` uses regex, so you need to escape the special characters in the urls (in this case, only the dots) with a backslash. Also append `.*` after the last slash in the urls to account for any possible querystrings.